# App with non-public APIs gets rejected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I made the MAC app and submitted for the review. But Apple has rejected the app and gave following reason;

> The use of non-public APIs can lead to a poor user experience should
>   these APIs change in the future, and is therefore not permitted. The
>   app includes ': OBJC_IVAR_$_NSWindow._contentView' from the framework
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit'.

I have used third party files of **OBMenuBarWindow.h** and **OBMenuBarWindow.m** files.

Can you please tell me what can be the issue? and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: The GitHub page for OBMenuBarWindow says "It does not use any private APIs, so it is Mac App Store compatible", and it doesn't seem to use _contentView. So it doesn't look like the culprit. Have you searched your project for _contentView?

Comment: It's easy to fool the automated checks by building the api name from a bunch of strings and using `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`